# How do I troubleshoot Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in updating a Media File?

Tags: query, media-library, troubleshooting

I'm on a shared hosting plan. Getting this error log entry when the user tries to update any field on a Media Attachment.

```
[13-Oct-2022 20:10:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /home4/example/public_html/examples/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2169
[13-Oct-2022 20:14:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /home4/example/public_html/examples/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 215
[13-Oct-2022 20:16:15 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /home4/example/public_html/examples/wp-includes/class-wp-post.php on line 254
[13-Oct-2022 20:24:29 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /home4/example/public_html/examples/wp-includes/class-wp-term-query.php on line 740
```

I've already
a) Deactivated all plugs
b) Switched to standard WP themes.

No difference.

What is the best strategy in determining why this update is timing out?

Is this a SQL issue? If so, is there a way to output that SQL query?

Comment: In WP 6.0.2, line 740 in `class-wp-term-query.php` is `$this->sql_clauses['orderby'] = $orderby ? "$orderby $order" : '';`, so have you tried clearing your caches (just in case), and disabling all MU (Must Use) plugins, if any? You could also try reinstalling core WP files via the Dashboard → Updates page in `wp-admin`. As for showing/inspecting the SQL queries, try [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) if you can... and then check the *Queries → Queries by Caller → `WP_Term_Query->get_terms`* (and other queries as well).

Comment: I'm embarrassed to ask this but, how do I determine which plugs are 'MU'? I don't -think- I have any of these installed. (At least, not knowingly.)

Comment: See https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/

Comment: OK, I understood that. I thought there might be something obvious I had missed. I added the Query Monitor plug-in and when I tried the same operation (updating a Media file), it brings up a blank screen. Off to study the plug-in. I (lazily) had simply hoped it would write the SQL query to the error log. Thanks.

Comment: I actually had a thought that you might simply need to increase the `max_execution_time` value in your PHP config (`php.ini`), e.g. to 90 (seconds)... but in my case, it's 30 and everything still worked properly for me. So I'm not sure, but try checking your Site Health → Info → Server settings - perhaps there's something that can help you identify the cause of the problem. Also, the [`query` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query/) might help you in inspecting individual SQL queries on the problematic page. But by "updating a Media file", what exactly did you update?

Comment: I can't recall the last time I had a timeout that wasn't indicative of some bug or temp server malfunction. SQL queries should be -fast-. I haven't done a thorough analysis, but I occasionally run into PDFs that are 'stubborn' for some reason. It may be unrelated, but the thumbnail may not generate or it may generate improperly. I think there is -something- in certain PDFs that WP struggles with? Or maybe I'm totally wrong. :D

Comment: Yeah, maybe there is  how large are those 'stubborn' PDFs and how complex their contents is? If you can share one of them, I can help confirm the issue (or whether this is server-specific or not). And when you said "update a media file", was it a PDF file, and is this just the Attachment Details modal on the Media Library page - if so, you could try checking the browser console for any errors - or is this also happening on the Edit Media page at `wp-admin/post.php`?